# Proof of time translation invariance of Brownian Motion. Missing assumption?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, solution-verification, brownian-motion

> **Proposition**: Let us consider a [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process) $W(t)$, $t\geq0$. For fixed $t_0\geq0$, the stochastic process $\widetilde{W}(t)=W(t+t_0)-W(t_0)$ is also a Brownian Motion.

> **Proof**: Let us take properties $1.$, $3.$ and $4.$ in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process) for granted as to stochastic process $\widetilde{W}(t)$ and focus on the proof of property $2.$ for $\widetilde{W}(t)$. First, consider that for any $s<t$:
> $$\widetilde{W}(t)-\widetilde{W}(s)=W(t+t_0)-W(s+t_0)\tag{1}$$
> To check property $2.$, we may assume that $t_0>0$. 
>  Then, for any $0\leq t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n$, we have $0<t_0\leq t_1+t_0<\ldots<t_n+t_0$. By property $2.$ for $W(t)$, $W(t_k+t_0)-W(t_{k-1}+t_0)$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ are independent random variables. Thus, by $(1)$, the random variables $\widetilde{W}(t_k)-\widetilde{W}(t_{k-1})$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ are independent and so $\widetilde{W}(t)$ satisfies property $2.$.

---

Starting from $0<t_0\leq t_1+t_0<\ldots<t_n+t_0$, I would say that property $2.$ does not necessary apply for $W_t$ in correspondence of $t=1$, since, **given the above assumptions**, I cannot be sure that, considering $W(t_1+t_0)-W(t_0+t_0)$, $(t_1+t_0)>(t_0+t_0)$, that is, in other words, that $W(t_1+t_0)-W(t_0+t_0)$ can be actually considered as an increment in time.

---

---

So, I would say that there is a **missing assumption so as that $(1)$ holds true for all $k\geq1$ and not just for $k>1$**, that is $$t_1>t_0\tag{2}$$ Would you agree with me as to the fact that assumption $(2)$ is necessary so as that $(1)$ holds true for $k=1$? If not, why am I mistaken?

Comment: We know, by assumption, that $t_0>0$. Indeed, suppose (for instance) $t_1=0$ and $t_0=1.2$. With such values, you would have that $(t_1+t_0)<(t_0+t_0)$, so $W(t_1+t_0)-W(t_0+t_0)$ would not be an increment in time of the Brownian motion $W$ @TSF

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get it. Could you please explicit why, with $k=1$, could I consider $W(t_1+t_0)-W(t_0+t_0)$ as an increment in time? @TSF

Comment: I just realized there is probably an error in your definition after all. Where did you find this "proof"?

Comment: It is from *"Introduction to Stochastic Integration"* by Kuo (2006). Are you referring to the same error I am pointing at? @TSF

Comment: It's more than that. Look at how increments are defined on the wikipedia page.

Comment: I cannot get the point. If you refer to this line: $$W \text{ has independent increments: for every }t>0\text{ the future increments } W_{t+u}-W_{t}, u\geq 0, \text{ are independent of the past values } W_{s}, s\leq t $$ I cannot see which is the difference with respect to Kuo definition. They seem to be equivalent @TSF

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_increments

Comment: What I would expect is in fact that:
$$W(t_n+t_0)-W(t_{n-1}+t_0)\perp \!\!\! \perp W(t_{n-1}+t_0)-W(t_{n-2}+t_0)\perp \!\!\! \perp \ldots\perp \!\!\! \perp W(t_1+t_0)-W(t_0+t_0)\hspace{0.6cm}\perp \!\!\! \perp W(t_0-0)=W(t_0)\tag{1}$$
Do you agree? (Obviously, the additional assumption for $(1)$ to hold true is that $t_1>t_0$) @TSF

Comment: No, because the requirement that the first increment in time $t_1$ be at least as large as your starting time $t_0$ isn't justified.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just rename $t_0$ to be $\tau$ and see if it doesn't fix things. You seem to be mixing the translating in time with the increments in time themselves.

> **Proof**: Let us take properties $1.$, $3.$ and $4.$ in here for granted as to stochastic process $\widetilde{W}(t)$ and focus on the proof of property $2.$ for $\widetilde{W}(t)$. First, consider that for any $s<t$:
> $$\widetilde{W}(t)-\widetilde{W}(s)=W(t+\tau)-W(s+\tau)\tag{1}$$
> To check property $2.$, we may assume that $\tau>0$. 
>  Then, for any $0\leq t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n$, we have $0<\tau\leq t_0+\tau<t_1 + \tau<\ldots<t_n+\tau$. By property $2.$ for $W(t)$, $W(t_k+\tau)-W(t_{k-1}+\tau)$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ are independent random variables. Thus, by $(1)$, the random variables $\widetilde{W}(t_k)-\widetilde{W}(t_{k-1})$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ are independent and so $\widetilde{W}(t)$ satisfies property $2.$.

Comment: Hence, in my reference, according to your restating, there is "just" the omission of the red part below? $$0<t_0\color{red}{\leq t_0+t_0}\leq t_1+t_0<\ldots<t_n+t_0$$ @TSF

Comment: No, it's not the same as that, I already answered you in the other comment. That condition doesn't make sense. The issue is calling the translation time, $\tau$, by the name $t_0$. This makes it seem like the first increment is $t_0$ when it's really $t_1$. $t_0$ is not an increment, it is the starting place. Do you see $\tau+\tau$ anywhere in my answer?

Comment: So, if you are just replacing $t_0$ with $\tau$, I would just expect $0<\tau<t_1+\tau<\ldots<t_n+\tau$ and not $0<\tau\color{red}{\leq t_0+\tau}\leq t_1+\tau\leq\ldots<t_n+\tau$ @TSF

Comment: I included a $t_0$ since it's how it was used in the definition. If you want to start from $t_1$ that's fine too but then you need to consider only $k=2,3,\ldots,n$. Do you understand what the mistake was now? Labelling both the translation and the increments as $t$ with a subscript confuses what conditions have to hold.

Comment: Maybe I am on the way. Sorry for my confusion. So, If I refer the the original reference, could we say that $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ part and $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ part below are two different "objects"?
$$\widetilde{W}(t)-\widetilde{W}(s)=W(t+\color{red}{t_0})-W(s+\color{red}{t_0})\tag{1}$$
$$0<\color{green}{t_0}\leq t_1+\color{blue}{t_0}<\ldots<t_n+\color{blue}{t_0}\tag{2}$$

Comment: The red and the blue are the same object. The issue is that you are calling this object by a name which makes it seem like it is the same type of object as $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n$ and it is not.